# Help reading some text

Tags: character-identification

[image]

Can you help me type out the text in this image?
I can only read the first line 没事吧？看你一拐一拐的？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

没事吧？看**你**一拐一拐的？

The rest are:

都是你的責任. 如果我的腿瘸了的話, 該怎麼參加籃球比賽? 我錯了!

This note contains contradictions and should be revised as below:

都是**我**的責任. 如果**你**的腿瘸了的話, 該怎麼參加籃球比賽? 我錯了!

However, it is difficult to believe that the writer would make that low-class mistakes, so it could be both were injured in the accident, and the original sentences could be interpreted as "It's all your fault. If I become lameness, how to participate in the basketball competition? I was wrong (**in joining you for the joy ride**). The words in bold are in the writer's head.

**Note:** @EEQ has correctly identified this note was written by two persons. So it makes sense now without the corrections and guesses.

Comment: I think this is a conversation between two persons. The first and last sentences are written by the person caused the injury, whereas the sencond one written by the injured. You can tell by the different handwriting.

Comment: Good observation. Maybe this was a note written by two classmates during the class.

Comment: This is an example of what's called "Note Passing", usually in a classroom environment, exchanging secretive, and often personal, information to pass the time in school, especially during lessons or classes students find boring.

Comment: Yeah, a teenager's thing :)